# npx react-native init AwesomeProject Failed with Error" node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:372 throw err;"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to install a react-native app using [React-Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) but it is throwing me this error.

[image]

I have tried. `npm init`, `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`, `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
They have all failed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am getting the same error, did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, just delete the 'npm-cache' folder

Comment: Yes this was the solution also i had to update my npm version

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.
Just delete `npm_cache` folder from the `Local` folder.
Try to follow the route below.

```
C:\Users\your-name\AppData\Local\npm-cache
```

That worked for me.